# how to output a json image file extension from a react applicaiton

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to output images from a JSON file with a image file name. Let me explain it.
Now the JSON file with the list of product are located under:
**frontend > src > product.json**

[image]

Here is the product.json fine:

```html
    "articles": [
        {
            "id": "233300",
            "name": "Lorem ipsum",
            "availability": {
                "isAvailable": true,
                "status": "1",
                "tooltip": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit",
                "text": "Available immediately",
                "richSnippet": "InStock"
            },
            "image": {
                "type": "LORENPPSBN",
                "file": "123456.jpg",
                "width": "139",
                "height": "400",
                "exists": true
            }
        },
```

Here it come the tricky part, where I need to combine the json file image name with the images folder, where obvious where the images are **frontend > public > images:**

[image]

I create a Product component where I to output the images as so:

```html
import React from 'react'
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Product = ({ articles }) => {
  return (
    <Card
      key={articles.id}
      className='my-3 p-3 rounded'
      style={{ width: '16rem' }}
    >
      <a href={`/articles/${articles.id}`}>
        <Card.Img src={articles.image.file} variat='top' />
      </a>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default Product
```

I would like to find a way to output those images that are coming from a separate folder. I can see in the URL  *http://localhost:3000/articles/233300* the image id. Any help or guide will be very welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Since your images are present under the images folder. You need to give that path on your code.

```
src={`/images/${articles.image.file}`}
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card } from 'react-bootstrap'

const Product = ({ articles }) => {
  return (
    <Card
      key={articles.id}
      className='my-3 p-3 rounded'
      style={{ width: '16rem' }}
    >
      <a href={`/articles/${articles.id}`}>
        <Card.Img src={`/images/${articles.image.file}`} variat='top' />
      </a>
    </Card>
  )
}

export default Product
```

Comment: Dear Yadab, thank you for that, such simple solution and I was breaking my head. Appreciate the help. - Do you know what would be the best option to get the styling also imported from the jso doc?  I appreciate the help

Comment: You can just do ‘import “css_file_path”’. Also you can accept this as a answer to your question.